# When trying to convey 'apparently', when do you use, だそう, and when do you use そう?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I have seen both `だそう` and `そう` written at the end of a sentence to convey "apparently". Do you use だそう when trying to convey "according to" (によると)?

Comment: Maybe not quite duplicate, but might help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5143/1173

Comment: See also http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/607, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2729, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/850

Comment: Is really だそう used as "apparently"?

Answer (score 9):

If the sentence ends in a verb or -い adjective, **do not** use -だそう. Here's an example:

> Nagano has delicious soba: 長野はそばがおいしいです。
> I hear Nagano has delicious soba: 長野はそばがおいしいそうです。
> According to the travel agency, Nagano has delicious soba：　旅行会社によると、長野はそばがおいしいそうです。

If the sentence ends in a -な adjective or a noun, use -だそう:

> Mount Fuji is beautiful: 富士山はきれいです。
> I hear Mount Fuji is beautiful: 富士山はきれいだそうです。
>   
> According to my sensei, Mount Fuji is beatiful:
>   先生によると、富士山はきれいだそうです。

The rule is this: take the plain form of the sentence (as if you're speaking informally), and add そうです.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that -そう is also used to mean "seems", but it is constructed differently. When expressing "seems", you use the **stem** of the predicate, as opposed to using the plain form. "彼は親切そうです。" means "He seems nice." Whereas "彼は親切だそうです。" means "I heard he's nice." So unless it's clear from the context, omitting the -だ is not an option.